# Reset one file to init state and remove all changes history

Tags: git

Is that posible to remove one file all changes history?

I wanted to reset one file to its initial state by:
git reset

Thats work fine,but is that posible to reset changes and history? (Not like now: creating new commit with reset changes )

Comment: You want to retain its initial commit and obliterate all references to other changes from history?

Comment: Yes, exactly ___

Comment: Look into [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/).